# Find $E(X)$, where $X$ is the sum of consecutive successes in $n$ Bernoulli trails.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be the sum of consecutive successes in a $n$ Bernoulli trails with parameter $p$.
for example, if $n=6$ and the results are $1,1,1,0,1,0$ then $X=2$.
I want to find $E(X)$ for $n \ge 2$  and $p \in[0,1] $.

I'd appreciate if someone can give me an initial hint to start solving the problem, or show a complete solution.

Comment: This is very standard. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering $0$ a success, and you want the total amount of successes in $n$ independent iterations, then you can define $Y$ a Bernoulli with parameter $p$, and then define $X=\sum_{k=1}^n 1-Y$, which adds $1$ anytime you get a $0$ in $Y$.

$X$ will be a Binomial with parameters $n$ (iterations) and $1-p$ probability of success at each iteration. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you finally do it?

Comment: yes. I think I got it.